# Sharing application context between JavaSE and Web Application

Tags: java, spring

I have a Java SE application running an embedded Jetty web server hosting a RESTful web service. I want to use Spring in both the Java SE part and in the web application running in Jetty. Some beans, e.g. a dao and the entity manager, needs to be shared between the two parts. When I start the application I get duplicate versions of both the beans and the entity manager.

```
WARN EntityManagerFactoryRegistry.addEntityManagerFactory:80 - HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (persistenceUnit) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'
```

In the Java SE part the first thing I do is to create the application context.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:server-context.xml","classpath:application-context.xml");
```

In the web application Spring is configured in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>example.restful.server.filter.SecurityFilterFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>example.restful.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

How can I make the web application use the application context already created instead of duplicating all the beans?

Comment: Caveat: It has been a while since I did something like this.  Try either removing the contextConfigLocation param from the servlet (I think this is wrong) or using an empty param-value for the contextConfigLocation.

Comment: Removing contextConfigLocation param results makes Spring look for the default location of the file which does not exist. Empty param-value results in NullPointerException in one of my classes when using a resource that is supposed to be injected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can create your own `ContextLoaderListener` and overriding `createWebApplicationContext` to return the ApplicationContext of your JavaSE app (assuming you have some kind of ApplicationContextHolder to keep a static access to it).

It seems easy, but you need to return a `WebApplicationContext` and not a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` to do this, I think you can do something like this:

```
public class MyContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener{
    protected WebApplicationContext createWebApplicationContext(ServletContext sc,
                                                        ApplicationContext parent){
        ApplicationContext javaSEAppContext = AppContextHolder.getAppContext();
        GenericWebApplicationContext context = new GenericWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
        context.setParent(javaSEAppContext);
        return context;
    }
}
```

And of course adapt your web.xml

```
    <!-- <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param> -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.company.MyContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: I've tried this solution but createWebApplicationContext is not called. A FileNotFoundException is thrown since Spring is looking for the default contextConfigLocation. I like the idea though.

Comment: I changed the signature of createWebApplicationContext exluding the second argument and it got called. But now I get the following error: ERROR ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext:308 - Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already associated with parent BeanFactory

Comment: Maybe overriding initWebApplicationContext can help. Look at the spring code and use it to derive an implementation that works for you.

Comment: I also overrided loadParentContext and return my Java SE app context and it worked! Thank you Ben!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to register your bean as a JNDI and then lookup for the JNDI to get a handle of the bean. Unfortunately as far as I am aware there is a MBeanExporter to register Mbeans but there isn't anything to bind a bean to the server's JNDI tree.

However developing a customer JNDI Exporter would not be very difficult as spring has an hook to JNDI - ***JndiTemplate***.So all you would need to do is create a class which implements the DisposableBean and with attributes like jndiName and jndiBean and use the below to bind the bean to the jndi name.

```
JndiTemplate.bind()
```

The spring xml should read something like this

```
<bean id="testBean" class="com.test.testBean"/>

<bean class="com.framework.JndiExporter">
   <property name="jndiBean" ref="testBean" />
   <property name="jndiName" value="com.test.testBean"/>
</bean>
```

Once this is registered, you can use the usual way to lookup the jndiTree for this jndiName.

Hope this helps to find a cleaner approach !

Comment: JNDIExporter will need to implement the InitializingBean as well