# Deploy tomcat webapp with different web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, web.xml

Is there a way of deploying a tomcat webapp with different web.xml (different name and context)?.

The problem:

I have a web.xml which i constantly have to modify (comment out and uncomment) stuff as i develop things - and this makes it a little annoying. Want i want to have is lets say two files:

```
web.xml
web-dev.xml
```

And I want my tomcat on my local machine to use web-dev.xml. Ofcouse for production release (i.e. Hosted server Tomcat will be using normal web.xml - web-dev.xml won't even be published). Its just for the development.

Any ideas where i can specify within tomcat to use web-dev.xml instead of web.xml ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using maven ? Use maven profiles, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298763/maven-customize-web-xml-of-web-app-project.

Comment: @HumbertoPinheiro I do use maven, but i do not want this to be maven specific solution.

Comment: @MaciejCygan, guess the only way to do this using Maven, Tomcat won't consider the different ones from `web.xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similarly to @HumbertoPinheiro, I think Maven profiles are a way to go.

Alternatively, this seems like a possible solution ([Reference link : Specify a custom web.xml to an embedded tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988578/specify-a-custom-web-xml-to-an-embedded-tomcat)):

```
Context webContext = tomcat.addWebapp("/yourContextPath", "/web/app/docroot/");
webContext.getServletContext().setAttribute(Globals.ALT_DD_ATTR, "/path/to/custom/web.xml");
```

Tested on Tomcat 7.0.42.